# Cache control static assets with query strings in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, caching

Do the cache control directives need to specify if a query string is present in the http request for proper matching?

Currently using query strings for static asset versioning, and disabled Etags for those - but the directives are not taking effect whatsoever. Looking at the headers, Etags are still used and there is no cache-control defined. Gmatrix and Lighthouse both state that static assets have no cache control set.

Example file requested: `app.js?v=1.3.5`

Here is the .htaccess file, followed by the troubleshooting steps

```sh
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# One month for media files and icons
<FilesMatch "\.(ogg|mp3|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|svg|webp|webmanifest|xml)\?.*$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

# One week for CSS/JS files except service worker file
<FilesMatch "^(?!sw).+\.(css|json|js)\?.*$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

# No cache for HTML files (checks with server for changes else serves cache)
<FilesMatch "\.(html)$">
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^(sw\.js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

### Troubleshooting steps

Directives don't seem to affect html pages either so assuming this may be a config or syntax issue.

- Check syntax with validator: https://www.lyxx.com/freestuff/002.html
- Ensure `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`
- Try setting `AllowOverride` to `All` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` for `/var/www/`
- Try adding the directives directly in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`
- Restart apache after changes: `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mod_headers` module was not activated!

Use `apachectl -M` to check for active modules (Debian/Ubuntu).

If headers module **not** listed:

Use `a2enmod headers` to activate the headers module.

Restart apache2 with `service apache2 restart` to implement changes.

At this point was able to test whether the query string needs to be added in the FilesMatch expression.
Turns out the query string needs to be omitted from the expression.

**Use: `\.(js)$`**

**Don't use: `\.(js)\?.*$`**